# Use value inside another PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress i'm currently using this function from a plugin `<?php the_field('event_boat'); ?>` to output the post ID for the selected field, which happens to be `5755` in this example.

As the plugin only allows me to output the post ID is it possible to incorporate the value from that function inside `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` to get the permalink based on the post ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the ID as a parameter in the get_permalink function, either by storing the ID value in a new variable, or just passing in the ACF-function directly as a parameter.

```
$post_id = get_field('event_boat');
echo get_permalink($post_id) // echoes out link for ID 5755
```

I'm using get_field() instead of the_field() because the_field() will echo out the value, We just want to pass it along.
We might aswell just do:

```
echo get_permalink(get_field('event_boat'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. :)

```
<?php $a = get_permalink(get_field('event_boat')); echo $a; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $a =get_permalink(get_field('event_boat')); echo $a; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. :)

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_field('event_boat')); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As you are both correct i'll have to accept the other answer as @ninja was first, but thank you!